# Bootstrap carousel does not start slide automatically on mobile web

Tags: javascript, html, css

My bootstrap carousel slides automatically when I am viewing it on my computer, but it does not on mobile I have to swipe it to get it started on using the carousel inside a react component.

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Adugnatad/stefan_project/draft/inspiring-albattani?file=%2FREADME.md

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" className="relative carousel slide h-full" data-interval="500" data-ride="carousel">
    <div className="carousel-inner">
        <div className="carousel-item active">
            <PageHero background='/assets/homepageHeroSvg.svg' mobileBackground='/assets/mobileBackgroundSvg.svg'>
                <Slide3 />
            </PageHero>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
            <PageHero background='/assets/homepageHeroSvg.svg' mobileBackground='/assets/mobileBackgroundSvg.svg'>
                <Slide1 />
            </PageHero>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
            <PageHero background='/assets/homepageHeroSvg.svg' mobileBackground='/assets/mobileBackgroundSvg.svg'>
                <Slide2 />
            </PageHero>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to get it started by clicking the button that contains the data-slide on useEffect but it just slides it that one time.

Comment: add your code to sandbox and share the link

Comment: @Sammed I have added the link above

Comment: Is your mobile browser up to date?